# Kendo Dataviz display text in chart marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-dataviz

I have a fairly normal Kendo Dataviz Scatter chart, with some customizations on the tooltip, but otherwise what you'd expect. What I want to do is display text (just a custom id number, up to 3 digits) in the middle of the circle/marker. I am having trouble with how to get the specific dataItem (my id) from the circle to display. I can access the circles (markers) with this:

```
var allcircles = $('svg g g').find('circle');
```

And from that I can get attributes such as the id and the data-model-id (which are different). I imagine Kendo is linking one or both of these ids to my specific dataItem Id somewhere (since when you click the marker it displays the correct tooltip)...but I haven't been able to link them myself. I have researched Kendo website, stackoverflow, google...but have found nothing. In debugging I have tried to look into the chart object-but there is so much to it I have had no luck.

Please let me know if you have an idea of what I can do. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am embarrassed to say, this is a built-in feature I overlooked. Its called series.labels, for future research.
Thanks so much to everyone who viewed!